# How to advertise online whilst being an individual and not a company

Tags: google-ads-api, ads

I recently tried to run an AdWords campaign to promote my web page.
When i tried to create a new campaign, google asks for my company information...which i dont have.

So...i googled for other popular online advertisers and they only offer advertising for registered companies too.

Are there any good ways to advertise a page or some content without having a company.

Comment: Not a programming question. Perhaps [webmasters.se] is a better fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to be a business, just leave it blank. Depending on your location though, you will be charged significant sales tax on your invoices.